# Time Complexity of Pairwise Graph Connectedness

Tags: reference-request, graph-algorithms, fine-grained

## The Setup

Consider the following algorithmic problem which, for now, I will call $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$.

**Input**: A natural number $|V|$, and a finite collection $\mathscr{E} = \left\{E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n\right\}$ of edge-sets.

**Output**: YES if there's a pair $E_i, E_j \in \mathscr{E}$ such that $G_{ij} = \left(V, E_i \cup E_j\right)$ is connected. NO otherwise.

Henceforth when I say $G_{ij}$ I mean $G_{ij} = \left(V, E_i \cup E_j\right)$.

Recall the $2\mathsf{OV}$ problem (or a variant thereof).

**Input**: A finite set $V = \left\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\right\}$ of $d$-dimensional boolean vectors.

**Output**: Yes if there's a pair $v_i, v_j \in V$ such that $v_i^T v_j = 0$. No otherwise.

$\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$ is at least as hard as $2\mathsf{OV}$, the latter of which has well established conditional lower bounds: assuming SETH, no randomized algorithm can solve $2\mathsf{OV}$ in $O\left(n^{2 - \varepsilon}\mathsf{poly}(d)\right)$ worst-case time for any $\varepsilon > 0$ when $d = \omega\left(\log(n)\right)$.
We can reduce $2\mathsf{OV}$ to $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$ in the following way:

- $|V| = d+1$
- $E_i = \left\{(k,d+1) \mid (v_i)_k = 0\right\}$ for all $i$.

If $v_i, v_j$ is a pair of orthogonal vectors, $G_{ij}$ is a $d$-tipped star with center $d+1$.

If $v_i, v_j$ is not a pair of orthogonal vectors, on the other hand, then $G_{ij}$ is not connected (there is at least one isolated vertex -- namely, the one corresponding to the coordinate in which both $v_i$ and $v_j$ are $1$).

## The Question

My main question is really about upper bounds. How does the running time of the best known algorithm scale with $d$ (for $\mathsf{2OV}$), and how does this scaling compare with $|V|$ (for $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$)?
What are the best known algorithms for $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$, for different parametrizations of $|V|$ as a function of $n$? Maybe we ought to even bring $\max |E_i|$ into the picture.

I'm particularly interested in when $|V| = \Theta(n)$ versus when $d = \Theta(n)$.

The best naive algorithm I can think of for $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$, right now, is essentially brute force: Find the minimum spanning forest of $G_i = \left(V, E_i\right)$ for all $i$, and then check all $G_{ij}$ for connectivity. This comes out to an $\tilde{O}(n^3)$ running time.

This pales in comparison to using matrix-multiplication for $\mathsf{2OV}$ when $d = n$; here there's an $O(n^\omega)$ time algorithm, where $\omega$ is the matrix-multiplication exponent.

The side question is a request for resources pertaining to types of graph problems similar to $\mathsf{2GraphConnector}$.
The input will be the same, but the output is YES if there is some $G_{ij}$ which satisfies any problem-dependent property (easy: acyclic, Eulerian; hard: Hamiltonicity, high clique number, etc). Or we could change $G_{ij}$ up and consider edge-set intersections instead of unions, etc.

Comment: If instead of looking for a single witness you want to know the answer for all pairs of graphs, then I think you can reduce Boolean Matrix Multiplication to that, meaning that it will be hard to find a truly subcubic "combinatorial" algorithm. This might of course be a harder problem and doesn't exclude improvements based on fast matrix multiplication.